# Having a classcast exception in android while using MyApplication class

Tags: java, android

**What i am doing**:: I am trying to use Myapplication class to send the data to next activity

**Problem i am facing**:: Having class cast exception

**BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.java**

```
public class BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters extends Activity{
    // Declare Variables
        JSONObject jsonobject;
        JSONArray jsonarray;
        ListView listview;
        ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype adapter;
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
        static String NAME = "rank";
        Button btn;

        String TYPE_FILTER;

        StringBuilder result;


        MyApplication mApplication;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mApplication = (MyApplication)getApplication();
            // Get the view from listview_main.xml
            setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

            TYPE_FILTER = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key_title");
            Log.v("---- Value-Start---", TYPE_FILTER);
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    result = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
                        if (adapter.mysparse.get(i) == true) {

                            result.append(arraylist.get(i).get(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.NAME));
                            result.append("\n");
                        }

                    }
                    Intent n = new Intent(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    n.putExtra("buffer", result.toString());
                    startActivity(n);
                }
            });

            // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
            new DownloadJSON().execute();
        }

        // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.this);
                // Set progressdialog title
                //mProgressDialog.setTitle("Fetching the information");
                // Set progressdialog message
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                // Show progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // Create an array
                arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                String newurl = "?" + "Key=" + TYPE_FILTER;


                // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://54.218.73.244:7005/RestaurantAtomicListItemType/"+newurl);

                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("restaurants");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        map.put(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.NAME, jsonobject.getString("MasterListMenuName"));

                        // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                        arraylist.add(map);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
                // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
                adapter = new ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.this, arraylist);
                // Set the adapter to the ListView

                mApplication.setArrayListMapData(arraylist);

                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                // Close the progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

**ResultActivity.java**

```
public class ResultActivity extends ListActivity {

    ListView lstView; 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); 
    String myName;
    MyApplication mApplication;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            map.put("key", "value"+i);
            arraylist.add(map);

        }

        String[] from = { "key" };
        int[] to = { R.id.textView1 };
        SimpleAdapter adapter= new SimpleAdapter(this, arraylist,R.layout.custom_single_list, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BreakfastLunchDinnerIndividualListOfItems"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_MainCourse" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_SideCourse" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Others" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Desert" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.ResultActivity" />
    </application>
    <application
        android:name="com.android.app.MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype.java**

```
public class ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype extends BaseAdapter implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    SparseBooleanArray mysparse;

    public ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        mysparse = new SparseBooleanArray(data.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView name;
        CheckBox chk;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_for_atomic_list_item_type, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_id_atomic_list_item_type);
        chk = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_atomic_list_item_type_id);


        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        name.setText(resultp.get(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.NAME));

        chk.setTag(position);
        chk.setChecked(mysparse.get(position, false));
        chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        return itemView;
    }

    public boolean isChecked(int position) {
        return mysparse.get(position, false);
    }

    public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        mysparse.put(position, isChecked);

    }

    public void toggle(int position) {
        setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mysparse.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
    }
}
```

**Log**::

```
01-03 13:30:12.828: D/AndroidRuntime(461): Shutting down VM
01-03 13:30:12.828: W/dalvikvm(461): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.multitabcheckboxselection/com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BreakfastLunchDinnerIndividualListOfItems}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.multitabcheckboxselection/com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.multitabcheckboxselection/com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BreakfastLunchDinnerIndividualListOfItems.onCreate(BreakfastLunchDinnerIndividualListOfItems.java:36)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  ... 11 more
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.onCreate(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.java:47)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-03 13:30:12.868: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  ... 20 more
01-03 13:30:15.563: I/Process(461): Sending signal. PID: 461 SIG: 9
```

---

### {Edit}

**BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.java**

```
public class BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters extends Activity{
    // Declare Variables
        JSONObject jsonobject;
        JSONArray jsonarray;
        ListView listview;
        ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype adapter;
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
        static String NAME = "rank";
        Button btn;

        String TYPE_FILTER;

        StringBuilder result;


        MyApplication mApplication;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mApplication = (MyApplication)getApplicationContext();
            // Get the view from listview_main.xml
            setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

            TYPE_FILTER = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key_title");
            Log.v("---- Value-Start---", TYPE_FILTER);
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    result = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
                        if (adapter.mysparse.get(i) == true) {

                            result.append(arraylist.get(i).get(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.NAME));
                            result.append("\n");
                        }

                    }
                    Intent n = new Intent(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    n.putExtra("buffer", result.toString());
                    startActivity(n);
                }
            });

            // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
            new DownloadJSON().execute();
        }

        // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.this);
                // Set progressdialog title
                //mProgressDialog.setTitle("Fetching the information");
                // Set progressdialog message
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                // Show progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // Create an array
                arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                String newurl = "?" + "Key=" + TYPE_FILTER;


                // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://54.218.73.244:7005/RestaurantAtomicListItemType/"+newurl);

                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("restaurants");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        map.put(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.NAME, jsonobject.getString("MasterListMenuName"));

                        // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                        arraylist.add(map);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
                // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
                adapter = new ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.this, arraylist);
                // Set the adapter to the ListView

                mApplication.setArrayListMapData(arraylist);

                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                // Close the progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
package com.example.multitabcheckboxselection;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void setArrayListMapData(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> setData)
    {
        arraylist = setData;
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getArrayListMapData()
    {
        return arraylist;
    }
}
```

### {Edit-3}

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BreakfastLunchDinnerIndividualListOfItems"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_MainCourse" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_SideCourse" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Others" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Desert" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.ResultActivity" />
    </application>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
package com.example.multitabcheckboxselection;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void setArrayListMapData(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> setData)
    {
        arraylist = setData;
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getArrayListMapData()
    {
        return arraylist;
    }
}
```

**Log**::

```
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.multitabcheckboxselection/com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BreakfastLunchDinnerIndividualListOfItems}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.multitabcheckboxselection/com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.multitabcheckboxselection/com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BreakfastLunchDinnerIndividualListOfItems.onCreate(BreakfastLunchDinnerIndividualListOfItems.java:36)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  ... 11 more
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.onCreate(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.java:47)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-03 14:13:14.509: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  ... 20 more
```

Comment: What is line 47 `BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.java`?

Comment: mApplication = (MyApplication)getApplication();

Comment: Remove the last<application> tag from manifest.xml. Each application having only one main <application> tag.. Plz see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the attribute

```
android:name="com.android.app.MyApplication"
```

to the first `application` element in the manifest and delete the second `application` element.

Btw. is your `MyApplication` class really in the package `com.android.app`?

EDIT: you use a different package, so the line should be

```
android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.MyApplication"
```

EDIT2+3: you have put it as an activity now. remove the activity, the attribute must go into the `application` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BreakfastLunchDinnerIndividualListOfItems"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_MainCourse" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_SideCourse" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Others" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Desert" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.ResultActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: @smriti3 imports are irrelevant, what does your `package` declaration say?

Comment: [+1] for pointing me that error ... I refelected the changes ..please have a look at edit2

Comment: @smriti3 you are not understanding what henry is saying. see this `<application
    android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.MyApplication"` in his post

Comment: @Raghunandan.....in the manifest i have mentioned as Henry posted ... <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name="com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </application> ........ i just want to correct my self where i am going wrong here

Comment: @smriti3 I have put the complete manifest file now as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
mApplication = (MyApplication)getApplicationContext();
```

Edit:

Delete the second application tag and move this to the first

```
   android:name="com.android.app.MyApplication"
```

Edit:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
private static MyApplication singleton;

public MyApplication getInstance(){
    return singleton;
}
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    singleton = this;
} 
   // other methods
}
```

Then in Activity

```
  mApplication = MyApplication.getInstance();
```

Example:

```
  public class Main extends Activity{

ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
MyApplication mapp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mapp = MyApplication.getInstance();
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText("My String from Application class is"+mapp.hello);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            map.put("key", "value"+i);
            arraylist.add(map);

    }
    mapp.setArrayListMapData(arraylist);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,MainActivity.class));
        }

    });

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{

    ListView lstView; 

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arraylist;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyApplication mApplication = MyApplication.getInstance();
        Log.i("................",""+mApplication.hello);
        lstView = getListView();
        lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);    
        arraylist= mApplication.getArrayListMapData();
        String[] from = { "key" };
        int[] to = { R.id.textView1 };
        SimpleAdapter adapter= new SimpleAdapter(this, arraylist,R.layout.row, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }   

}
```

MyApplication

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    private static MyApplication instance = null;  
    public String hello= "Hello global Application";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
    }
    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
           instance = new MyApplication();
        }
        return instance;
     }
    public void setArrayListMapData(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> setData)
    {
        arraylist = setData;
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getArrayListMapData()
    {
        return arraylist;
    }
}
```

Manifest file

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name="com.example.testlistactivity.MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testlistactivity.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name="com.example.testlistactivity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
    </application>
```

Snap1

[image]

Snap2

[image]

Comment: @smriti3 try Henry's suggestion along with mine

Comment: @smriti3 check the edit with example using singleton

Comment: please see the edit3 ....looks everything is fine ...still same error exists ....and example is for my reference ?

Comment: @ Raghunandan .... i resolved manifest part .... [+1] for example .... my result set is not proper .... :( ok thanks for this guidance

Comment: @smriti3 what do you mean by result set s not proper/ you should get it working by looking at the example.

Comment: not not like that ...your example is perfect.... what i meant was ... if my business case is not functioning .... with question's context .... this is right

Comment: @smriti3 specify what is the problem and i might be able too help further

Comment: @Raghunandan... I practiced your example code .... according to your code class Main puts values ..... Value1 -- Value10 .... i can see it in result class in your snapshot .... can u make a another class that puts item1--- item10 ..... now display the result Activity .... i want to know how result looks .... i am hoping list will be Value1----Value10.. followed by Item1---Item10 .... i am confused only when there are 2 classes using same MyApplication

Comment: @smriti3 yes it is. that is exactly what is happening in my code. I don't understand what you mean by value 1 to 10 followe by item1 to 10

Comment: Ill try and get back on this post , Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally one would do like this

```
class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     mInstance = this;
}

static public MyApplication getInstance() { return mInstance; }

static private MyApplication mInstance;

}
```

Then from elsewhere

```
MyApplication myApp = MyApplication.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change**

```
mApplication = (MyApplication)getApplication();
```

**To**

```
mApplication  = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext());
```

And in Manifest.xml define `android:name="MyApplication"`

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="MyApplication"  >
```

Edit

Remove this

```
<application
        android:name="com.android.app.MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </application>
```

Each application will have only one `<application>` Tag

Comment: I refelected the changes ..please have a look at edit2