# Use get and setters throw activities - Update Static Var's

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, static-methods

I'm trying update my `serverBuffer` and automatically pass values ​​between two activities. In the first activity `MainActivity`, I create the functions for a later use in another activity `ListActivity`.

The problem is when I pass the variable it is always null. Can anyone help me?

In MainActivity, my notificationList is automatically updated.

```
private static ArrayList<String> notificationsList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In ListActivity, I try this:

```
list = MainActivity.getNotificationsList();
```

Always get a null pointer, with or without information on the list.

Comment: you can use application class.

Comment: I tried it with an example taken from stackoverflow. But I could not implement the concept itself.

Comment: Assuming `ListActivity` is launched from `MainActivity` you can pass notificationList using EXTRA.

Comment: @Urbester did you check my post does it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass data between activities use intents instead of static variable.

`ArrayList` implements serializable so you can use intent to pass the list.

If you want to maintain a global state you can use Application class, but i guess intents should be the choice i this case.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(ActivityName.this,SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key",yourlist);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Then in SecondActivity get the list

```
 ArrayList<String> list = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("key");
```

If you wish to use Application class you can refer this

[Using MyApplication class in android for JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930400/using-myapplication-class-in-android-for-json-data)

Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    ArrayList<String>> arraylist;

    public static MyApplication instance=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance()
    {
        if(instance==null)
        {
            instance=new MyApplication();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void setArrayListData(ArrayList<String> setData)
    {
        arraylist=setData;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getArrayListData()
    {
        return arraylist;

    }
}
```

In manifest application tag android:name"packagename.MyApplication"

Then in Activity

```
  MyApplciation mapp = MyApplication.getInstance();
  mapp.setArrayList(yourlist);
```

Similarly use `getArrayList()`

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. The idea is the following, I have a task that is always receiving information from a server. This information is placed in an ArrayList. This ArrayList is passed to various activities. And I want this argument suffers updates so I can always have an updated anywhere in the application list.

Comment: @Urbester use Application class

Comment: Sorry, but how? I searched some tutorials on the internet and even answers here on stackoverflow, but could not implement correctly.

Comment: @Urbester CHECK MY POST

Comment: @AndréLizardo update : Application class is a singleton. In of the stackoverflow posts dianne hackborn has suggested use a singleton of your own instead of application class. Also to pass data between activities there is a third party library that i use it most apps of mine called Eventbus from green robots